# How to upload file using python selenium-webdriver when there is no input type but instead it has a button type in HTML?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How to upload file using python selenium-webdriver when there is no input type but instead it has a button type in HTML?

I'm trying to upload a file to a webpage using Selenium but the HTML type is a button not an Input file.

Below is the HTML Code

[image]

Button looks like this

[image]

My code

```
browser.find_element_by_class_name("ng-scope").send_keys('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test.png')
```

But after I run the code the file is not uploaded.

Please advise on where i'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance
-M

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a hidden input with `type=file`. To upload file using Selenium yo have to send keys to `input[type=file]`:

```
browser.find_element_by_css_selector(".file-upload-input input[type=file]").send_keys('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test.png')
```

Use `WebDriverWait` to wait element to be present in the DOM:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# ...

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 5)

wait.until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, ".file-upload-input input[type=file]"))).send_keys('C:\\Users\\Desktop\\test.png')
```

Comment: That works like a charm thank you Sers:)

I didn't understand the wait part. Sorry very new to automation. correct me if i'm wrong. It basically waits until the file is uploaded is that correct?

Comment: No, it's wait until element `input[type=file]` will appear in the HTML